# How to get the font metrics of a QPainter outside paintEvent?

Tags: qt, fontmetrics, qt5

How to get the font metrics of a QPainter outside paintEvent drawing method? I would need this before painting on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to do text layout outside of your paint event, just create a QFontMetrics from the font you will be using.

Comment: Which font is this one? if we do not set it manually?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011238/how-do-you-get-system-default-font-settings-in-qt