# How do you get the system default font size in Qt?

Tags: qt, fonts

Qt uses `9px` as default font size, but users (on Linux) can change this by using `qtconfig`.

So, how do I get the system default font size? I read the documents, but I can not find any API.

Comment: This answer might be of some help.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011238/how-do-you-get-system-default-font-settings-in-qt

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Get a default font QFont object and read the size from it.

Answer (score 5):

Your application default font can be obtained from `QApplication::font()`, which

> [Returns the default application font.](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#font)

And you can gather a size of it using `pointSize()`,`pointSizeF()`,`pixelSize()`, etc.

Comment: Won't work in my case
Be careful, it could be -1 in some cases =(