# Increase font size in Qt

Tags: qt, fonts, qt5

I have a GUI with some math symbols that might be hard to read at the default font size, so I would like to create a `QFont` object that has a size of `system_default+4`.

However, there doesn't seem to be a way to get the default size in the first place, and I don't want to hardcode a size that might be even smaller than what the user is using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question and answer [How do you get the system default font size in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175913/how-do-you-get-the-system-default-font-size-in-qt) suggests that a QFont object starts with the system default. Also, the API docs indicate that the default QFont constructor does this (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfont.html#QFont), and also suggests `QGuiApplication::font()` as another way to get the default font.

So you could do something like

```
QFont f;
int defaultFontSize = f.pointSize();
```

to obtain the system default. To increase the font size just increment this value by 4, create a QFont with this size (or use `setPointSize` to modify an existing font obj), and set the font on the label displaying your math symbols.