# Qt: Longer term adaption to run Application unmodified/independent of Display Resolution

Tags: c++, qt, layout, qtstylesheets

I am going through [High Dpi](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html) information on `Qt` Website. I basically have an old application which needs to be run on `High DPI` touchscreen display. Every icon seems small. I want planning to set some enviroment variables and setAttributes to enable my application work with minimal time. However, I came across the last line in the above link which says:

> In the longer term, the application should be adapted to run unmodified:
>
> 1. Always use the qreal versions of the QPainter drawing API.
> 2. Size windows and dialogs in relation to the screen size.
> 3. Replace hard-coded sizes in layouts and drawing code by values calculated from font metrics or screen size.

I am not able to understand how to achieve the last point in `QSS` because font size can't be set in terms of percentage. Please help me to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I don't think it's about style sheets. What you've quoted is for [migration of existing applications](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html#migration-of-existing-applications).

The last sentence is an extension of the second one.

---

Let's assume you have hard-coded values (thus fixed) to define the sizes of your windows, widgets, layouts, ... and one day you want to change your screen to another one with a different resolution, size, dpi, ... then your hard-coded values may not be adapted and therefore break your display.

To fix it and make your application portable, you will need to define your sizes relative to something dependent on the screen specifications. Same things for the font metrics.

So, when you defines, for example, the `sizeHint()` of a custom widget (if needed), don't return absolute/hard-coded values but instead return values in relation to the parent container, the screen geometry, ... Whatever you want that will be dynamically adapted on another hardware/platform setup. As much as possible.

*Qt* provides methods to get the actual screen geometry such as `QDesktopWidget()::screenGeometry()`.

For example, if you want to define the main window size, you can write something like:

```
// Assuming that MainWindow inherits QMainWindow

MainWindow::MainWindow
{
    resize(QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry().width()/2, QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry().height()/2);

    // ...
}
```

The `MainWindow` object will now have half the size of the screen, whatever the screen.

---

**EDIT:** For the font sizes, any default-constructed `QFont` will already be adapted to the system preferred size. See the following SO thread: [How do you get the system default font size in Qt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175913/how-do-you-get-the-system-default-font-size-in-qt)

Comment: @abhiarora A default-constructed [`QFont`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfont.html) will already be adapted to the system preferred size. But if you really want to specify it manually, as you wanted to create environment variables, you could create one that contains your desired point size and pass it to the `QFont` constructor or by using [`setPointsize()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfont.html#setPointSize).

Comment: I was wondering if I could specify it in QSS file and read the stylesheet and change the font size to a scaled size.

Comment: @abhiarora From the [reference documentation about stylesheets](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-properties), you have a `font` and specifically `font-size` property to set it from your _qss_ file. But I don't know how to calculate relative sizes from a description file like _qss_ except by redefining from the code via `QWidget::setStyleSheet()`.

Comment: @abhiarora From the code, you can read the _qss_ file, and then add the desired font size by doing something like: `my_widget->setStyleSheet(my_widget->styleSheet().append("MyWidget {font-size: the_value_you_want;}"));` But do not specify it in the _qss_ file, you'll complete the stylesheet from the code with the desired value.