# What are the standard for fonts when distributing a program?

Tags: python, fonts, pyqt

I developed a program with PyQt, and I'll soon start to diffuse it. I still have a problem, however.

What are the standards about the fonts ? For now, I force my app to use the Lucida family. All the widgets have this font:

```
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Lucida"))
```

Is it a good idea to do that ?

On Linux for example, you can choose the font for all the programs you run. So I don't know if forcing the user to use a font is a good thing.

If it's not the standard way,what would you do ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011238/how-do-you-get-system-default-font-settings-in-qt). That sets the default as the font. Based on [this](http://thenextweb.com/dd/2011/03/02/whats-the-most-readable-font-for-the-screen/) it seems Helvetica and Arial are some of the more readable fonts, so for your default, you might want to try that.

Comment: If you do not set a special style, you already have the default plattform style in Qt. Wouldn't this also include using the default plattform font?

Comment: Actually, a simple app.font(), before any font modification, gives the default OS font. Then, you can apply it on all the widgets you want (I was thinking about the QWebView, not concerned by app.setFont(font).

Answer (score 0):

Usually there will be a guide to user for setup their preferences, so the correct way is either using the default font, or after user choose their own font, you save their preferences to `QSettings`, when next time the program is launched, it could reload the last time saved configuration.