# How to change font size (in percent) of QLabel widget using setStyleSheet?

Tags: python, css, pyqt5, pyside2

I am looking for a simple way to make a larger text size for a title label in my PySide2 app. This is a learning project. I prefer to use a style sheet to change the label font. I also do not wish to use hard coded point sizes because that may not work well on different display sizes.

This other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40861305/dynamically-change-font-size-of-qlabel-to-fit-available-space) looks interesting, but it is too complex for me at this time. Is there a simple way to make a larger font, such as `font-size: 200%`? I tried exactly that and so far it is not working.

When I use a %, the font size does not change at all. When I set a specific size such as `font-size: 20px` it produces the expected results.

I'm not finding the Qt docs to be of much help (probably because I don't know my way around them yet.) Here's my code:

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt

class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("My Title")
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter | Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("font-weight: bold; font-size: 200%")
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.label)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative font sizes in QT or the most portable way to define them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381154/relative-font-sizes-in-qt-or-the-most-portable-way-to-define-them)

Comment: @Laif thanks, but that doesn't seem to answer my question because it is over 10 years old and applies to a different Qt version. I would hope a lot has changed since then.

Comment: You'd be surprised sadly

Comment: @Laif - yes, that is sad. Sorry I doubted you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Qt does not support using percentage as font size as noted by [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-properties):

> The font size. In this version of Qt, **only pt and px metrics are
>   supported.**

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>